# Form window alert, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms

i got the problem with validation in my form. Validation actualy works in every explorer, but how is it possible to receiving an empty form in my mail box. I dont understand..thanks for any help!

```
<script>
function kontrolaDat(myForm){
    if (window.RegExp) 
    { 
        znaky=new RegExp("^[^.]+(\.[^.]+)*@([^.]+[.])+[a-z]{2,3}$"); 
        if (!znaky.test(myForm.email.value)) 
        { 
            window.alert("Zadaný e-mail nie je platný!");  
            return false; 
        }
    }
    if(myForm.jmeno.value == "") {
    alert("Zadajte prosím svoje meno");
    return false;
    }
    if(myForm.telefon.value == "") {
    alert("Zadajte prosím váš ​​telefón");
    return false;
    }
    if(myForm.psc.value == "") {
    alert("Zadajte prosím vaše PSČ");
    return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
</script>

<div class="span4 text">
 <h4>Najlepšiu hypotéku aj vám!</h4>
 <p>Žiadne poplatky - Žiadne záväzky - Skvelý servis<br />Vyplňte formulár a my vás budeme kontaktovať.</p>
 <form method="post" action="hypoteka-dakujeme.php" onsubmit="return kontrolaDat(this);">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Emailová adresa" />
  <input type="text" name="jmeno" placeholder="Vaše meno" />
  <input type="text" name="telefon" placeholder="Kontaktný telefón" />
  <input type="text" name="psc" placeholder="PSČ" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Chcem najlepšiu hypotéku!" class="btn tlacitko" />
 </form>
</div> <!-- End text -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you disable JavaScript no validation is done. Validate  the form on the server side - in hypoteka-dakujeme.php before sending the email. You should never use client side validation only - it can be easily bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

Please rephrase your question, you say in the title that the `alerts` in the form does not work, but then you say that the validation via `JavaScript` is working properly and the problem is that you get the email with no data.

So if the `JavaScript` works as expected .. focuses attention on the `PHP` that receives and processes the data sent.

I would start by adding the following code at the top of the file `hypoteka-dakujeme.php`

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

...then, you must debug the code to print on screen (for example) the information you expect to receive in the email.

If you get the information you expect, then send the email. If you still get an empty email... check the `mail()` function that you are using.

**If need more help, please rephrase the question including relevant information.**

Good luck any way.